# Decode Function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table named as transaction,in that table trans_type column is there.I want to check the trans_type like bellow

```
if(trans_type = 'AR','AD','AF','AG') then
trans_type:='A';
elsif trans_type = 'BA','BS','BD','BG' then
trans_type:='B';
end if;
```

How to write this one by using decode function? Kindly tell me answer.

Comment: Surely you tried something yourself? What didn't work?

Comment: select sr_cd,to_char(trunc(transdate,'mm'),'YYYYMM')     Month,sum(quantity) Receipt                  from transdetail
where transtype IN('STKREC','RP','RECADJ','SRET') and trunc(transdate,'mm') 
between '01-April-2013' and '31-March-2014'
group by trunc(transdate,'mm'),sr_cd;

Comment: I want to update one column with sum(qty) based on trans_type('AR','AD') and update another column with sum(qty) based on trans_type('BA','BS')

Answer (score 2):

Note that for some cases, an `if` **statement** can be turned into a `case` **expression** which is somewhat similar to the `?` operator in C and Java, but more generic. Your pseudo-code:

```
if(trans_type = 'AR','AD','AF','AG') then
trans_type:='A';
elsif trans_type = 'BA','BS','BD','BG' then
trans_type:='B';
end if;
```

becomes:

```
case
  when trans_type in ('AR','AD','AF','AG') then 'A'
  when trans_type in ('BA','BS','BD','BG') then 'B'
end case
```

as a `case` **expression**.

Answer (score 1):

```
trans_type = DECODE(trans_type, 'AR', 'A', 'AD', 'A', 'AF', 'A', 'AG', 'A'
                  ,'BA', 'B', 'BS', 'B', 'BD', 'B', 'BG', 'B')
```

or more easily, if those are all the values for the field

```
trans_type = substr(trans_type, 1, 1)
```